Blazor: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace
I'm trying out blazor but I find myself stuck at the creation of a project. Creating a project succeeds but it doesn't build saying:

The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace

I tried creating other projects multiple times, moving the content of Component folder into a new one, clean and rebuild but nothing seems to work. I tried looking around but I haven't found anything that could help me... What am I doing wrong here?


Whatever you've blanked out probably has an illegal character of some sort.  Deploy using the same template with Blazor as the solution/project name and it will work.

that's not it. It was Chris's answer that fixed it for me.
Thanks for your time though =D

I just ran into a similar error and I believe it is related to the analyzer warning you have above your error message.
There is a thread here about that warning.
How to fix "The analyzer assembly references version '4.7.0.0' of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version '4.6.0.0'."
Using the global.json file did not work for me, but its worth a try. I fixed the error by upgrading the version of Visual Studio 2022 I had installed on the machine. The update was to version 17.9.6, and after a clean I was able to build successfully.

Hey @Chris, I tried with the other versions of vs studio i had installed (2022 community and 2019 pro) and it worked. I was so fed up that I just reinstalled my vs studio 2022 pro and no problems. So I guess you're right! Thanks for helping mate!

I had similar issue. App was running without problem but I had this error saying  "The type or namespace name 'Components' deas not exist in the namespace 'xxxx' (are you missing an assemly reference?). I did right click on project and selected 'Analyze and Code Cleanup' then 'Run Code Cleanup (Profile 1) and (Profile 2) in order.  That cleared up the unnecessary error.
